# making all customer when any users has value

Tags: powerbi, dax

Date:

| Customer | Sales | User | Last Order | Order Sent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 |  | abc |  |  |
| 1001 |  | afe |  |  |
| 1001 |  | wr3 |  |  |
| 1002 |  | avc | 1/1/2021 | Yes |
| 1002 |  | abc |  |  |
| 1003 |  | abc | 1/1/2021 | Yes |

I have the table above and I need a "Dax formula" that will label the Sales as yes for all users for each customer if the last order has a date value in it. or order sent is Yes, I'm open to either.

When I can make a filter that would show if that one line has an order but I need help making the entire customer for sales if they have placed an order.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRfMK.png), you can calculate Sales using a measure like this:

```
Sales = CALCULATE(
    MAX(Customers[Order Sent]),
    ALLEXCEPT(Customers,Customers[Customer]))
```

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYJ4j1SX0QE) is a good example of how to calculate the max within a group using a measure.